# Toggle body class with styled-components and React setState

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I'm trying to open an off-canvas menu and then apply `overflow-y: hidden;` on the rest of the document to prevent scrolling. This is surprisingly difficult given how React and `styled-components` works with `state`.

How would I go about accessing `body`? I really don't want to use `document` to get/set because this is SSR Gatsby site and that will throw errors. Is there a native way to drill up that high with this stack?

```
import React from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'

import NavMenu from '../NavMenu/navmenu.js'

// Styles, w/ styled-component syntax
const HeaderBG = styled.header`
  background-color: ${props => props.theme.purple};
  padding: 5px 25px;
`
const HeaderContainer = styled.section`
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: ${props => props.theme.xl};
`

const NavMenuButton = styled.div`
  cursor: pointer;
`

const NavMenuLine = styled.div`
  background: #fff;
  height: 2px;
  margin: 5px 0;
  transition-duration: .15s;
  transition-property: transform, opacity;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  width: 25px;
`


// Header component
class Header extends React.Component {

  // Initial menu state is closed (false)
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      menuStatus: false
    }
  }

  // Toggles menu open/close state
  menuToggle = () => {
    this.setState( prevState => ({
      menuStatus: !prevState.menuStatus
    }))
  }

  render() {
    return (  
      <div>
        <HeaderBG>
          <HeaderContainer>
            <NavMenuButton onClick={ this.menuToggle } menuState={ this.state.menuStatus }>
              <NavMenuLine></NavMenuLine>
              <NavMenuLine></NavMenuLine>
              <NavMenuLine></NavMenuLine>
            </NavMenuButton>
          </HeaderContainer>
        </HeaderBG>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: I might be misunderstanding you, but accessing `document` in an event handler is fine for SSR since the handler will never be run on the server.

Comment: @Tholle - I think you're right and that's how I was approaching this, but it just feels wrong. Is using `document` the right way to do this?

Comment: Some imperative logic is usually fine. Alternatively you could keep a piece of state in your topmost component that you use to flip the `overflow-y: hidden;` on and off with inline styles on the topmost element in the component if you want to do it declaratively, instead of setting the overflow on the body.

Comment: @Tholle - didn't think about the declarative route and just using my top-level component. I'd worry a bit about the framework injecting something over the top of me but that's a pretty good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using (or can upgrade to) the version 4, you can use the new [`createGlobalStyle` helper](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/api#createglobalstyle). The nice thing is that you can instantiate it everywhere in your code.

Comment: I'll take a look. I think I'm on 3.x but could probably upgrade easily.

Answer (score 2):

In fact you can use the new '[createGlobalStyle](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/api#createglobalstyle)' I quickly put together an example for you.

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import {createGlobalStyle} from 'styled-components';

const GlobalStyles = createGlobalStyle`
    overflow-y: ${({menuOpen}) =>
      menuOpen && hidden };
  }


export default class GlobalCss extends React.Component {
  state = {
    menuOpen: false
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    document.body.addEventListener('onToggleMenu', this.onMenuOpen, true);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
     document.body.removeEventListener('onToggleMenu', this.onMenuOpen, true);    
  }

  onMenuOpen = event => {
      this.setState({
        menuOpen: !this.state.menuOpen
      });
    }
  };

  render() {
    return <Styled.GlobalStyles menuOpen={this.state.menuOpen} />;
  }
}
```

You add the component in your top-level component as

```
  <GlobalStyles />
```